# Using array element as an object member variable isn't working in php 7

Tags: php, arrays, object

The following code works fine in php 5.3.3 but failed when I upgraded to 7.  I use this construct a lot and shudder to think I have to change it everywhere.

```
<?php
$a=array();
$a['one']='uno';
$a['two']='dos';
$b=new stdClass();
$b->uno=1;
$b->dos=2;
$b->$a['two']=3;
print_r($b);
print "\n";
```

It prints
    PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/gaares/a.php on line 8

```
stdClass Object
(
    [uno] => 1
    [dos] => 2
    [Array] => Array
        (
            [two] => 3
        )

)
```

on PHP 7 and prints

```
stdClass Object
(
    [uno] => 1
    [dos] => 3
)
```

On PHP 5.

Is there any way I can encourage PHP 7 to dereference the array  and use the value of $a['two'] instead of stopping the scan at the array?  I use this construct in Waaayyyy too many places to want to change the code to

```
<?php
$a=array();
$a['one']='uno';
$a['two']='dos';
$b=new stdClass();
$b->uno=1;
$b->dos=2;
$c=$a['two'];
$b->$c=3;
print_r($b);
print "\n";
```

Which makes it do what I expect.

Comment: `$b->{$a['two']} = 3;`

Comment: The use of curly braces fixed the problem.  I don't look forward to fixing this in dozens of cases over multiple projects, however.